# Java - How to delete an element in a vector

Tags: java, vector, sum

How do I remove an element in a vector?

```
 public boolean delete(int no)
 {
      if (!search(no)) 
      {
          return false;
      }

     vec.remove(no - 1);
     size = size - 1;
     return true;
 }
```

This is my remove function. It deletes single digits. If I try to delete say a double-digit, it would delete the wrong number

Comment: In regards to calculating the sum, at the moment it just assigns `i` to sum with each iteration. Instead, `sum += vec.get(i);` You should move the declaration and initialisation `int sum = 0;` into the method as well otherwise it won’t work correctly after the first call.

Comment: that didn't work. i got an error that said bad operand types for binary operator '+'. first type = int; second type = Object

Comment: Please show more details about `vec`, i.e. declaration and instantiation.

Comment: i only declare it and initialize it in the statement

Comment: Well if it's `Vector vec = new Vector();` it will not work as you do not the define the parameterized type, so it's treated as `Object`, this will cause you a headache, require manual casting and will not enforce compile time type checking. `Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<>();` will resolve these issues, and is the correct way to use any generic class. Personally I'd consider using `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` (depending on how its used) over `Vector`, unless thread safe behavior is required, since it has the overheads of being synchronized.

Comment: hey this worked man, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain an Iterator from your vector. It provides safe methods to remove entries. BTW, I can't see all your code, but ArrayList avoids synchronization overhead.